# How to properly structure C# nested classes to receive complex JSON

Tags: c#, json, class

I am passing JSON object back to a C# aspx page web method.

My JavaScript looks like:

```
 return jsonItem = {
                     id: id,
                     title:  title,
                     registrationPage: {
                        registration: registration                              
                     }                                                  
                   }
```

I am passing this item to an aspx web method:

```
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "SaveXML.aspx/SaveAs",
          data: JSON.stringify({ jsonItem : jsonItem }),
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",                
          dataType: "json",
          success: function (msg, textStatus) {
                alert(textStatus);
          },
    });
```

**The JSON payload is being sent fine**.

In the aspx page I have the classes:

```
public class JSONItem
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }  
    public RegistrationPage RegistrationPage { get; set; }           
}

public class RegistrationPage
{
     public string Registration { get; set; }
}

[WebMethod]
public static Policy Save(Policy policy)
{
}
```

When I try building this I get a code analysis error, which makes sense:

> CA1034 : Microsoft.Design : Do not nest type  'SaveXML.RegistrationPage'. Alternatively,  change its accessibility so that it is not externally visible.

**If I ignore the error, the code does work. I did try changing the modifiers but then the Registration Page object wasn't populated.**

How do I get the code to work and comply with the above error?

Thanks

Comment: Odd that you get this warning for the `RegistrationPage` class but not the `JSONItem` class.

Comment: Thanks, yeah.  I would prefer to keep the classes nested.  I like the simplicity of this line:  data: JSON.stringify({ jsonItem : jsonItem }) - and don't want to pass in more than one object into the save method.

Comment: My answer, while it lasted, was talking about nested class definitions; I thought you defined `RegistrationPage` inside `JSONItem` (`class JSONItem { class RegistrationPage { ... } ... }`). There shouldn't be anything wrong with having a nested _instance_ of the class, so that warning mystifies me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the localisation of your WebMethod it looks like you have nested `JSONItem` and `RegistrationPage` inside your `Page` class. To be exact your code looks like this:

```
public partial class MyPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    ...

    public class JSONItem
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }  
        public RegistrationPage RegistrationPage { get; set; }           
    }

    public class RegistrationPage
    {
         public string Registration { get; set; }
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static Policy Save(Policy policy)
    {
    }

    ...
}
```

You should move those classes out of `Page` class (they can remain in same file of course):

```
public class JSONItem
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }  
    public RegistrationPage RegistrationPage { get; set; }           
}

public class RegistrationPage
{
    public string Registration { get; set; }
}


public partial class MyPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    ...

    [WebMethod]
    public static Policy Save(Policy policy)
    {
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  This is what I needed.  I'll be moving the classes to a separate file anyway.